# cleverbotfreeapi Exception has occurred: KeyError 'cboutput'

Tags: python-3.x

For the first few minutes everything worked normally, however, after a while when trying to get a response an error is shown :

```
Exception has occurred: KeyError
'cboutput'
```

In terminal:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\Users\krzysiek\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.4.765268190\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\__main__.py", line 45, in <module>
    cli.main()
  File "c:\Users\krzysiek\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.4.765268190\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 444, in main
    run()
  File "c:\Users\krzysiek\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.4.765268190\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 285, in run_file
    runpy.run_path(target_as_str, run_name=compat.force_str("__main__"))
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 263, in run_path
    pkg_name=pkg_name, script_name=fname)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\1Projektypython\cleverbot\test.py", line 3, in <module>
    print(cleverbotfreeapi.cleverbot("Hello."))
  File "C:\Users\krzysiek\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\cleverbotfreeapi\cleverbotfreeapi.py", line 46, in cleverbot
    response = requests.utils.unquote(req.headers["CBOUTPUT"])
  File "C:\Users\krzysiek\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\requests\structures.py", line 54, in
__getitem__
    return self._store[key.lower()][1]
KeyError: 'cboutput'
```

My code:

```
import cleverbotfreeapi

print(cleverbotfreeapi.cleverbot("Hello."))
```

Answer (score 0):

In the cleverbotfreeapi.py file you have to change:

```
response = requests.utils.unquote(req.headers["CBOUTPUT"])
```

To:

```
getresponse = re.split(r'\\r',str(req.content))[0]
response = getresponse[2:-1]
```

It seems like the header CBOUTPUT doesn't exist anymore.